# GIT + cocos2d-x: What files can I add to gitignore?

Tags: git, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am working with cocos2d-x 3.0 and want to use git.
I only want to save important files to git and not auto generated files from vs 2013/logfiles/....
Is there somewhere a .gitignore file for cocos2d-x which ignores everything not necessary?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, you can easily decide what is important to you and what isn't if you dont want to save build files, add that directory to .gitignore. Nobody can really tell you this except to give you what THEY decided to ignore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get started, try this:

```
# Mac
.DS_Store

#Java
*.class

# XCode
*.moved-aside
build/*
*.xcworkspace
*.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
*.pbxuser
!default.xcworkspace
!default.mode1v3
!default.mode2v3
!default.pbxuser
*.perspectivev3
profile
xcuserdata
.idea/*

#Cocoa pods
*.old
Pods/*

#cocos2d-x
libs/
bin/
obj/
assets/
gen/
out/
.classpath
.project
.cproject

# backup files
*.bak
*.bak[0-9][0-9]
*.orig
*.orig[0-9][0-9]

# source packages - anywhere
*.tar.bz2
*.tar.gz
*.tar
*.tgz
*.gtgz
```

Comment: Thanks! VS 2013 creates a .gitignore with some default-settings. I added these files too. I also thought about adding https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/v3/.gitignore 
Any comments?

Comment: This is a great list.

Comment: What about the `/cocos2d/` directory? It's about 300MB in size and not written by me.

Answer (score 1):

Everything that is not a part of the code sources you are creating does not have to go into git.

This would include dependency libraries (including cocos), build output folder and I would also exclude all assets since those would be the most bulky stuff that does not necessarily change as often or need team contribution facilities that git provides (unless you are actually involved in asset production which I assume you are not).